# How to run a query condition for only certain organizations in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which has a condition to eliminate certain rows from the output. I need this condition to run for only two organizations. For the rest it should by pass the condition and return all the rows. This is the query

```
        SELECT lines.customer_trx_id customer_trx_id,
               lines.unit_selling_price,
               lines.customer_trx_line_id customer_trx_line_id
           FROM mtl_units_of_measure uom,
                ra_customer_trx_lines_all lines,
                ra_customer_trx_all trx
        WHERE trx.customer_trx_id = lines.customer_trx_id
              AND trx.complete_flag = 'Y'
              AND lines.uom_code = uom.uom_code(+)
              AND lines.line_type = 'LINE'
              AND trx.customer_Trx_id =1
              AND lines.unit_selling_price <>0
              AND lines.description NOT LIKE '%PROM%DISCOUNT%'
              AND lines.description NOT LIKE '%TIER%DISCOUNT%'
```

The last two conditions should run for only orgs 1 and 2 but not for org 3. the field name for org is org_id.

Comment: show the output you get and the one you expect. By the way, why are you using that old syntax ? Use ANSI SQL is always better and easy to read.

Comment: ANSI-92 SQL introduced `JOIN` syntax almost ***three decades*** ago.  Using `,` and `(+)` has been deprecated in most environments.  Stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know which table org_id belongs to , so i just added it as `org_id` below. Just some extra pharantesis and `OR` condition can do the trick i think, just make sure that `org_id` doesnt contain null's :

```
SELECT lines.customer_trx_id customer_trx_id,
               lines.unit_selling_price,
               lines.customer_trx_line_id customer_trx_line_id
           FROM mtl_units_of_measure uom,
                ra_customer_trx_lines_all lines,
                ra_customer_trx_all trx
        WHERE trx.customer_trx_id = lines.customer_trx_id
              AND trx.complete_flag = 'Y'
              AND lines.uom_code = uom.uom_code(+)
              AND lines.line_type = 'LINE'
              AND trx.customer_Trx_id =1
              AND lines.unit_selling_price <>0
              AND 
             ( (lines.description NOT LIKE '%PROM%DISCOUNT%'
               AND lines.description NOT LIKE '%TIER%DISCOUNT%'
               and org_id in (1,2)) or 
               org_id not in (1,2)               
              )
```

Comment: the condition (lines.description NOT LIKE '%PROM%DISCOUNT%'
               AND lines.description NOT LIKE '%TIER%DISCOUNT%' should fire if the org id is 1 or 2 and eliminate the records having the description containing PROMO etc. For any other org this condition should not fire,

Comment: i didnt undestand, can you give some explanation on sample data ?

Comment: see the sample output. 

112111753 -4.57 827623762 10 LINE TSP_PROMO_DISCOUNT.promo1490004 1

This row should not come in the output where the org is not 1 or 2.

Comment: what is the org_id ?  its so hard to help like this. please create your schema here http://sqlfiddle.com/ and we undestand what you mean

Comment: I got the solution, Thanks for your help. Will post the solution in a little while.